OAuth verification,google cloud console for mobile app using Flutter with firebase
I had an app and i am going to publish it very soon and first I needed to do the oauth verification. For that I needed to provide the YouTube video demonstrating the scope uses. However, I am concerned with showing the oauth clients used, and i cant show it directly as it is mobile app and using flutter with firebase. I am not able to show the client id directly, in the video. How can i adress this issue?
I have seen videos around this, and all of them show the oauth client used in their app. Also google also says to specify to show the clients used, but i am not able to show it in the video as it doesn't redirect to the browser. Can I submit without showing the clients used?
